# What are these symbols used for?

Tags: notation

I do not understand these symbols.

- a.s.
- e.g.
- i.e.
- c.f.
- ...

Comment: How is your Latin coming along?

Comment: en.wiktionary.org/

Comment: “e.g.” means “for example”. “i.e.” means “that is”.  “cf.” means “compare”.  I don't know what ‘a.s.” means unless it is an abbreviation for “almost surely”. You should buy a dictionary, and learn to  use it.

Comment: This is in no way unique to mathematics--I've seen these used in all sorts of texts, and use them myself in everyday correspondence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [Wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations) for a nice list of mathematical abbreviations.

Mathematically, a.s. is used to shorten "almost surely."

And a.e. is used to shorten "almost everywhere."

You might also want to consult the [list of mathematical jargon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_jargon), particularly if English isn't your native language, and even if it is!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 6):

as such & almost surely, exempli gratia (as an example), id est (that is), (cf.) confer (see, consult), $\dots=\dots$.

Comment: I think i.e. stands for id est

Comment: While you're at it, how about adding "etc." et cetera (and so on...)

Comment: I've seen "s.t." to mean such that, so that, subject to, and similar phrases.

Comment: Yes correct, will edit. By the way, it would be nice to have a site were we can find all mathematical abbreviations (like WLOG, QED, etc.) Does it exist?

Comment: [Wikipedia's list of mathematical abbreviations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_abbreviations).

Comment: as @amWhy stated (but deleted his comment?), a.s. usually means almost surely EDIT: see his other answer

Comment: @Zubin - nice! Thanks.